# Xamarin android Camera2 usage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera

I want to use camera2 on my android project into Xamarin studio (Mac).
I set reference from Camera to Android.Hardware.Camera2, but all method from camera are in error.

I can't use Camera2.Open(), or Camera2.Parameters.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Camera 2 works on Android L or later
> 2. Xamarin.Android 4.17 or later is needed

Sample code is here

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic

> For version lower than Android L use  Android.Hardware.Camera

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Camera/

Sample code is here

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Graphics/CameraPreview.cs

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8705/camera-sample

Comment: So i can't use it because my project target Android device below Android L?

Comment: You shall use Camera Sample. Which is depreciated now
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Camera/

Comment: this is a project from scratch which in I added support for camera, but with no specific android target platform.